# What does 8GK100K mean?

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.1, cartography, scale, design

I have a lot of mosaic datasets:

```
Zone8GK100k, Zone9GK100k, ... , Zone7GK25k, ... , Zone7Gk50K, ... , Zone7GK200K.
```

As I know, 7GK, 8GK... are utm zone numbers.

1) What does 25K, 50k, 100k, 200k mean?

2) What is the relation between these numbers and the ArcGis scales (1:1 000, 1:10 000, 1:24 000, 1:100 000, 1:250 000 ...)?

***Update:***

Thanks. I have layer Zone9GK200k. So, I set: "In beyond 1:200 000". What minimum scale(out beyond) for this layer do I set?

Comment: Looks like a custom grid naming scheme to me. [UTM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system) zone numbers (11N, 22S, etc.) don't normally look like that. Where did the data come from? Does it include metadata describing its coordinate system and naming convention?

Comment: Your update sounds like a different question to your original (1+2) above so I recommend that you post it as such.

Comment: Spatial reference is Pulkovo_1942... Sorry, the reference is not UTM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

100K is short for 100 thousand (kilo) and is used as shorthand for a scale of 1:100,000.

This can be extrapolated to the other examples.

For completeness 8GK appears to stand for **[Pulkovo 1942 / Gauss-Kruger zone 8](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/28408/)**.

Comment: Thanks. I have layer Zone9GK200k. So I set: In beyond 1:200 000. What minimum scale(out beyond) do I set?

Comment: This sounds like a different question to your original (1+2) above so I recommend that you post it as such.